# scala play form how handle java bigdecimal

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, type-conversion, bigdecimal

I try to fill a form with the values of System

```
  def edit(id: Long) = IsAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
    User.findByEmail(username).map { user =>
      System.findById(id).map { system =>
      Ok(html.systems.editForm(id, systemForm.fill(system), Person.options, user))
    }.getOrElse(NotFound)
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }
```

but some of 'system' values are java.math.BigDecimal

```
 val systemForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[BigDecimal]),
      "sys_name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "sys_desc" -> nonEmptyText,
      "sys_owner1_id" -> longNumber,
      "sys_owner2_id" -> optional(longNumber)
    )(System.apply)(System.unapply)
  )
```

and it says :

```
type mismatch; found : (anorm.Pk[java.math.BigDecimal], String, String, String, Option[String], java.math.BigDecimal, Option[java.math.BigDecimal]) => models.System required: (anorm.Pk[java.math.BigDecimal], String, String, Long, Option[Long]) => ?
```

how can i handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem in anorm or somewhere near.

As you may see from error description `sys_owner1_id` and `sys_owner2_id` are `BigInteger`s in query result, but declared as `long` in form.

I am not familiar with anorm, but solution is to declare these ids as long in anorm, or declare them as `BigInteger` in form mapping or convert from `BigInteger` to `long` in your query.

Comment: thanks - im forced to use java BigDecimal as that what Oracle JDBC uses for number types - but the form helpers wont work with them... i cant thinkk of a way round it. I wish they put on the website you cant use play with Oracle before I began. I spoke to someone at typesafe but they just said ditch anorm and use SLICK - but theres hardly any doc and its not integrated into play yet